# purrr iterate or loop over all columns (similar to function that counts and sum or subtract variables)

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse, purrr

I would like to find here some insights to solve a very practical issue. Let's say I have two time-points (w0 and w1) and I want to subtract (or sum) all specific paired values. Measure 1 at time 1 and measure 1 at time 2, measure 2 at time 1 and measure 2 at time 2.

I'm more familiar with tidyverse environment (purrr will be desirable) and that's the code I have to simulate the real dataset

Any hunt is wanted.
Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)
ds <- data.frame(w0_1=rnorm(10,1,2),
                 w0_2=rnorm(10,3,3),
                 w0_3=rnorm(10,3,2),
                 w1_1=rnorm(10,2,1),
                 w1_2=rnorm(10,3,3),
                 w1_3=rnorm(10,5,4))


ds %>% 
  summarise(dif_1 = mean(w0_1, na.rm=T)-mean(w1_1, na.rm=T))

ds %>% 
  summarise(dif_2 = mean(w0_2, na.rm=T)-mean(w1_2, na.rm=T))
```

By the way, I know the following code will not work, but that's is the rationale behind my question

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  ds %>% 
    summarise(dif_1 = mean(w0_[[i]], na.rm=T)-mean(w1_[[i]], na.rm=T))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `purrr` approach, you can first split the dataframe into groups of 3 and then use `pmap_dbl()`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

split.default(ds, (seq_along(ds)-1) %/% 3) %>%
  pmap_dbl(~ mean(.x - .y))

      w0_1       w0_2       w0_3 
-0.8563246  0.3441249 -2.8411739
```

In response to OP's comments about full dataset having 12 variables at the two time points, and assuming the vars are in order and have no missing values:

```
dataset %>% 
  select(starts_with("w4"), starts_with("w0")) %>%
  split.default((seq_along(.)-1) %/% (ncol(.)/2)) %>%
  pmap_dbl(~ mean(.x - .y))
```

Comment: Thanks much, but If instead of having a ds I need to select certain variables, such as w0_1:w0_3, w1_1:w1_3. This -> split.default(ds, select(w0_1:w0_3, w1_1:w1_3)) %>%
  pmap_dbl(~ mean(.x - .y)) does not work.

Comment: OK - you'd simply select the variables before splitting - `ds %>%
select(starts_with("w0"), starts_with("w1")) ...`

Comment: Thanks. I am almost there. In my real dataset, I have 12 variables for the first measurement and 12 variables for the second.
This is close, but something is going on. Could you please fix the following? Thank you. dataset %>% select(starts_with("w4"), starts_with("w0")) %>% 
  split.default(., (seq_along(.)-1) %/% 3) %>% 
  pmap_dbl(~ mean(.x - .y))

Comment: The last question, in case I have missing data, the results can be tricky: pmap_dbl(~ mean(.x - .y, na.rm=T)) seems to work, but I don't know if the results are reliable.

Comment: @Luis - With missing values you may want to change it to `mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE) - mean(.y, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 2):

Using @fmarm's data, here is a non-tidy approach:

```
(ds.mean <- colMeans(ds, na.rm=TRUE))
#   w0_1  w0_2  w0_3  w1_1  w1_2  w1_3 
#  1.264 3.747 2.733 2.121 3.402 5.574 
(ds.diff <- ds.mean[paste0("w0_", 1:3)] - ds.mean[paste0("w1_", 1:3)])
#     w0_1    w0_2    w0_3 
#  -0.8563  0.3441 -2.8412
```

If the number of w0's is known (3 in this case), it is simpler:

```
(ds.diff <- ds.mean[1:3] - ds.mean[4:6])
#    w0_1    w0_2    w0_3 
# -0.8563  0.3441 -2.8412
```

Comment: Much simpler answer than mine, +1

Comment: Very nice and easy solution! Thank you so much !! +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, there is probably something simpler

```
ds %>% pivot_longer(names(ds),names_to=c('g0','g1'),names_pattern= '^(w.*)_(.*)') %>% # convert to long format
       group_by(g0,g1) %>% # group by g0 = (w0 or w1) and g1=(1,2,3)
       summarise(value=mean(value,na.rm=TRUE))   %>% # get mean by group
       pivot_wider(names_from=g0,values_from=value) %>% # pivot to get three lines
       mutate(dif = w0-w1) %>% # difference of mean by group
       select(g1,dif) %>% # keep only useful columns
       pivot_wider(names_from=g1,names_prefix='dif_',values_from=dif) #pivot again to have everything in one line

# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  dif_1 dif_2 dif_3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 -0.856 0.344  -2.84
```

You did not set a seed so our results may vary, I used `set.seed(1)`.

No loop or need of purrr, the idea is if you have to make loops it means your data needs to be reshaped using `pivot_longer` for example

I suggest you run it step by step to see what the code does on each line, each step is a basic transformation.

Comment: The mean for `w0_1` is 1.264 and for `w1_1` is 2.121 so `w0_1 - w1_1` is -.856.

Comment: @dcarlson right thank you, I was doing `w1-w0` instead of `w0-w1`

Comment: Wow, thanks much. This is a very elegant solution. I was missing dplyr now uses pivot_longer (instead of gather / spread). Now, I am trying to understand the argument "names_to".